# Запрос системного пароля в программе на Python

Tags: python, безопасность, python-2.x, xubuntu, password

Подскажите, как в программе на python, при определенных действиях, запросить пароль пользователя(sudo). Например, хочу я чтобы какие-то файлы моей программы хранились в папке в домашней директории(home), для этого нужно создать директорию(например /home/user/folder), как сделать, чтобы в этом моменте система запросила пароль и если он правильный создала папку?
Система Xubuntu 18.04. Python 2.7.

Comment: Запросила пароль суперпользователя? Зачем, если это директория пользователя?

Comment: @mkkik это был просто пример. Суть  в том, что при определенных действиях нужно запрашивать пароль sudo  и, если он правильный, передавать управление обратно программе и выполнять ее дальше.

Comment: Можете вообще требовать запуск скрипта от имени суперпользователя. Просто в процессе выполнения пользователь будет получать `PermissionError` без `sudo`. Сложно что-то сказать, если вы не говорите, какие именно действия хотите выполнить.

Comment: я бы с радостью сказал, если это поможет делу. Но хотел посмотреть на общую реализацию. Пока еще не знаю, какие именно действия. Мне нужно понять, как это вообще делается. Как-то проверять файл с паролем в системе или, как вы говорите, запускать от имени sudo скрипт? Мне не понятен механизм проверки системного пароля в сторонних программах. Я могу написать код, который будет хранить пароль(не системный) где-нибудь на сервере или в файловой системе, но это будет пароль именно от этой программы а я хочу взаимодействовать с ОС. Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Извиняюсь за обилие текста.

Comment: Проверку пароля лучше доверить ОС. Сами же просто формируйте системный вызов с `sudo`. Например, `os.system('sudo ...')` или `subprocess.run(['sudo', ....])`.

Comment: @mkkik Понимаю, что прошу о многом, но можете показать пример такого вызова? Короткий фрагмент кода.

Comment: Посмотрите ответы к этому вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13045593/6166540

Comment: это звучит как [XY-задача](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044): в фактическом решении вы к примеру просто один раз файлик в /etc/sudoers.d добавляете, чтобы не запрашивать пароль во время выполнения вашего скрипта.